# Determining Number of Joint Sessions Per Product Pair

Tags: pyspark

I have this data-frame:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow

rows = sc.parallelize([[1, "A"], [1, 'B'] , [1, "A"], [2, 'A'], [2, 'C'] ,[3,'A'], [3, 'B']])

rows_df = rows.toDF(["session_id", "product"])

rows_df.show()

+----------+-------+
|session_id|product|
+----------+-------+
|         1|      A|
|         1|      B|
|         1|      A|
|         2|      A|
|         2|      C|
|         3|      A|
|         3|      B|
+----------+-------+
```

I want to know how many joint sessions each product pair have together. The same products can be in a session multiple times, but I only want one count per session per product pair.

Sample Output:

```
+---------+---------+-----------------+
|product_a|product_b|num_join_sessions|
+---------+---------+-----------------+
|        A|        B|                2|
|        A|        C|                1|
|        B|        A|                2|
|        B|        C|                0|
|        C|        A|                1|
|        C|        B|                0|
+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

I'm lost on how to implement this in pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the joint session count for pairs that have joint sessions is fairly easy. You can achieve this by joining the DataFrame to itself on `session_id` and filtering out the rows where the `product`s are the same.

Then you group by the `product` pairs and count the distinct `session_id`s.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

rows_df.alias("l").join(rows_df.alias("r"), on="session_id", how="inner")\
    .where("l.product != r.product")\
    .groupBy(f.col("l.product").alias("product_a"), f.col("r.product").alias("product_b"))\
    .agg(f.countDistinct("session_id").alias("num_join_sessions"))\
    .show()
#+---------+---------+-----------------+
#|product_a|product_b|num_join_sessions|
#+---------+---------+-----------------+
#|        A|        C|                1|
#|        C|        A|                1|
#|        B|        A|                2|
#|        A|        B|                2|
#+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

(Side note: if want ONLY unique pairs of products, change the `!=` to `<` in the `where` function).

The tricky part is that you also want the pairs that don't have joint sessions. This *can* be done, but it won't be efficient because you will need to get a Cartesian product of every product pairing.

Nevertheless, here is one approach:

Start with the above and RIGHT join in the Cartesian product of the distinct products pairs.

```python
rows_df.alias("l").join(rows_df.alias("r"), on="session_id", how="inner")\
    .where("l.product != r.product")\
    .groupBy(f.col("l.product").alias("product_a"), f.col("r.product").alias("product_b"))\
    .agg(f.countDistinct("session_id").alias("num_join_sessions"))\
    .join(
        rows_df.selectExpr("product AS product_a").distinct().crossJoin(
            rows_df.selectExpr("product AS product_b").distinct()
        ).where("product_a != product_b").alias("pairs"),
        on=["product_a", "product_b"],
        how="right"
    )\
    .fillna(0)\
    .sort("product_a", "product_b")\
    .show()
#+---------+---------+-----------------+
#|product_a|product_b|num_join_sessions|
#+---------+---------+-----------------+
#|        A|        B|                2|
#|        A|        C|                1|
#|        B|        A|                2|
#|        B|        C|                0|
#|        C|        A|                1|
#|        C|        B|                0|
#+---------+---------+-----------------+
```

Note: the `sort` is not needed, but I included it to match the order of the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do it:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

joint_sessions = rows_df.withColumnRenamed(
    'product', 'product_a'
).join(
    rows_df.withColumnRenamed('product', 'product_b'),
    on='session_id',
    how='inner'
).filter(
    F.col('product_a') != F.col('product_b')
).groupBy(
    'product_a',
    'product_b'
).agg(
    F.countDistinct('session_id').alias('num_join_sessions')
).select(
    'product_a',
    'product_b',
    'num_join_sessions'
)

joint_sessions.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't include  the `B`, `C` pair

Comment: @pault how does it not? or do you mean it doesn't show the `num_join_sessions  = 0` cases?

Comment: Yes it doesn't include the `0` cases.